# ¿Cómo listar enlaces simbólicos de un directorio en específico?

Tags: unix, línea-de-comandos, búsquedas

¿Cómo puedo filtrar los enlaces simbólicos a un directorio en específico?

Estaba usando éste comando:

```
find ./ -type l -ls 2>/dev/null
```

Me devuelve todos los enlaces buscando desde la raíz anulando algunos mensajes de error.

Hasta ahí todo bien, pero son muchos resultados.

¿Cómo filtro los enlaces a todo lo que comienza con: `/directorio*`?

Gracias por su ayuda, saludos!

Comment: Creo que no hace falta filtrar el resultado, sustituye el parámetro `./` por `/directorio` o por `./directorio`, según sea el caso, y la búsqueda ocurrirá solamente dentro de ese directorio. ç

Comment: Hola @jachguate si requiero filtrar porque todos los enlaces que requiero están en /

Comment: también podes limitar cuanto se baja usando `-maxdepth 1` o `-maxdepth 2`

Comment: o bien usa el parámetro `-path "./Directorio/*"`

Answer (score 0):

Para filtrar la *salida* del comando `find`, puedes hacer una *tubería* hacia `grep` y utilizar allí una expresión regular para filtrar los resultados.

Por ejemplo, si el directorio siempre inicia con `/directorio`, esto debiera devolverte el resultado (o estar cerca, no tengo una terminal a mano para probarlo, pero te da la idea).

```
find ./ -type l -ls|grep ^\/directorio
```

Comment: parsear la salida de ls es complejo y peligroso. ¿Y si hay nombres de fichero con salto de línea? Mejor usar las herramientas que ofrece el propio `find`

Comment: buen punto, aunque diría que afectará solo en un pequeño porcentaje de los casos. No digo que no haya que considerarlo nunca, lo mejor es una solución robusta y económica, a veces toca elegir entre ambas.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Veo que cuando abro el archivo con nombre de dos líneas `a\nb` con el geany se abren dos archivos `a` y `b`, interesante, no sabía eso.

Comment: @Eslacuare sí, debes usar comillas para leerlo bien: `vi "a\nb"` o similar.

Answer (score 0):

Lo hice pasando la salida al `sed`:

```
find ./ -type l -ls  | sed -r "s/.*(\.\/)/\1/g"
```

Mi salida de la búsqueda fue:

```
558609      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           21 may 28 17:18 ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 -> liblber-2.4.so.2.11.5
558611      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           23 may 28 17:18 ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2.11.5
558610      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           18 may 28 17:18 ./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2
558577      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           21 may 28 17:18 ./usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 -> liblber-2.4.so.2.11.5
558605      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           23 may 28 17:18 ./usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2.11.5
558604      0 lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     root           18 may 28 17:18 ./usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2
```

Lo que hago es encontrar el primer punto y descartar todo lo anterior:

```
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2 -> liblber-2.4.so.2.11.5
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2.11.5
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2
./usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2 -> liblber-2.4.so.2.11.5
./usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2.11.5
./usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2 -> libldap_r-2.4.so.2
```

Ahora, para separar el enlace del archivo real, se le puede pasar la salida al `cut`:

```
find ./ -type l -ls | \
  sed -r "s/.*(\.\/)/\1/g"  |  \
  cut -d ">" -f 1  | cut -d " " -f 1
```

Enlaces:

```
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap-2.4.so.2
./usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2
./usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
./usr/lib64/libldap-2.4.so.2
```

Para los archivos reales, se cambia los unos por los doses:

```
find ./ -type l -ls | \
  sed -r "s/.*(\.\/)/\1/g"  |  \
  cut -d ">" -f 2  | cut -d " " -f 2
```

Salida:

```
liblber-2.4.so.2.11.5
libldap_r-2.4.so.2.11.5
libldap_r-2.4.so.2
liblber-2.4.so.2.11.5
libldap_r-2.4.so.2.11.5
libldap_r-2.4.so.2
```

Además, podría concatenarse con el primero para tener una ruta absoluta:

```
a="$(find ./ -type l -ls | sed -r "s/.*(\.\/)/\1/g")"

b1="$( printf "$a" | \
  cut -d ">" -f 1 | \
  cut -d " " -f 1 | \
  sed -r "s/(.*)\/.*$/\1/g")"

b2="$(printf "$b1" | \
  cut -d ">" -f 2 | \
  cut -d " " -f 2 )"
```

Rutas obtenidas:

```
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
./usr/lib64
./usr/lib64
./usr/lib64
```

Ahora se concatenan la ruta y el archivo, se puede iterar con cualquiera de las dos variables, porque las dos tienen la misma cantidad de archivos:

```
i=2
for a in $b1;do
    printf "$(printf "$b1" | head -n $i | tail -n -1)/"
    printf "$(printf "$b2" | head -n $i | tail -n -1)"
    echo ""
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Archivos reales:

```
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.11.5
./usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
./usr/lib64/liblber-2.4.so.2.11.5
./usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2.11.5
./usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
./usr/lib64/libldap_r-2.4.so.2
```